# Advantages of dynamic linking with either ld utility vs. dlfcn API?

Tags: c, linux, unix, linker

I am doing some research into platform independent code and found mention of the dlfcn API. It was the first time I came across mention of it and did further research into it. Now hopefully my lack of experience/understanding of platform independent code as well as compiling/linking isn't going to show in this post but to me the dlfcn API just lets us do the same dynamic linking programmatically that the ld utility does. If I have misconceptions please correct me as I would like to know. Regarding what I think I know about the ld utility and the dlfcn API I have some questions.

**What are the advantages of using either the ld utility vs. dlfcn API to dynamically link?**

My first thought was that the dlfcn API seems like a waste of my time since I need to request pointers to the functions vs. having ld examine a symbol table for undefined symbols and then linking them. Similarly ld does everything for me while I have to do everything by hand with the dlfcn API (i.e. open/load the library, get a function pointer, close the library, etc.). But on second glance I thought that there may be some advantages. One being that we can load a library out of memory after we are done using it.

In this way memory could be saved if we knew we didn't need to utilize a library the whole time. I am unsure if there is any "memory/library" management for libraries dynamically linked by ld? Similarly I am unsure of what scenarios/environments would we be interested in using the dlfcn API to save said memory as it seems this wouldn't be a problem in modern day systems. I presume one would be the usage of the library on a system with very very very limited resources (maybe some embedded system?).

What other advantages or disadvantages may there be?

**What "coding pattern" is used for platform independent code in regards to dynamic linking?**

If I was making platform independent code that depended on system calls I could see myself achieving platform independent code by coding in one of three styles:

1. Logical branching directly in my libraries code via macros. Something like:
  ```
  void myAwesomeFunction()
  {
       ...
  #if defined(_MSC_VER)
       // Call some Windows system call
  #elif defined(__GNUC__)
       // Call some Unix system call
       ...
  }
  ```
2. Create generic system call functions and use those in my libraries code. Something like:
  ```
  OS_Calls.h

  void OS_openFile(string myFile)
  {
       ...
  #if defined(_MSC_VER)
       // Call Windows system call to open file
  #elif defined(__GNUC__)
       // Call Unix system call to open file
       ...
  }

  MyAwesomeFunctions.cpp

  #include "OS_Calls.h"

  void myAwesomeFunction()
  {
       ...
       OS_openFile("my awesome file");
       ...
  }
  ```
3. Similar to one but add a layer of abstraction by using the dlfcn API
  ```
  MyLibraryLoader.h

  void* GetLibraryFunction(void* lib, char* funcName)
  {
      ...
      return dlsym(lib, funcName);
  }

  MyAwesomeFunctions.cpp

  #include "MyLibraryLoader.h"

  void myAwesomeFunction()
  {
      Result result = GetLibraryFunction(someLib, someFunc)(arguments...);
  }
  ```

What ones are typically used and why? And if there are any others that aren't listed and preferred to mine please let me know.

Thanks for reading this post. I will keep it updated so that it may serve as a future informative reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dlfcn and ld does not solve the same problem: in fact you can use *both* in your project.

The dlfcn API is meant to support plugin architectures, in which you define an interface which modules should implement. An application can then load different implementations of that interface, for various reasons (extensibility, customization, etc.).

ld, well, links the libraries your application request, but does that at *compile* time, not at runtime time. It doesn't support in any way plugin architectures, since ld links objects specified in the command line.

Of course you can only use the dlfcn API, but it is not meant to be used in that way and, of course, using it in that way would be a huge pain in your rectum.

For your second question, I think the best pattern is the second one.
Branching "directly in the code" can be confusing, because it's not immediately obvious what the two branches accomplish, something which is well-defined if you define a proper abstraction and you implement it using multiple branches for each supported architecture.
Using the dlfcn API is pretty pointless, because you don't have a uniform interface to call (that's exactly the argument that supports the second pattern), so it just adds bloats in your code.

HTH

Comment: I guess I am a little confused about what ld did then. So then at compile time ld dynamically links the libraries in executable. This creates a symbol table that has undefined symbols as a result. Then at runtime the libraries are dynamically loaded. Is this correct or rather dynamically linking != dynamically loading? It seems that unless I really misunderstood their meaning they are equivalent to each other. Also what does the loading of the libraries at runtime? Thanks for your help as well. :)

Comment: Your comprehension of the matter is pretty accurate. As for ld, it's "dynamic" in the sense that the actual linking is done at **loading** time, while the API is "dynamic" in the true sense of the word.

Comment: There are 3 kinds of linkage. Static linkage means ld makes a big binary with everything. Dynamic linkage means ld sets references, which are resolved by the loader when the executable starts running. Dynamic loading (maybe I'm not using accurate terms here) is when the executable can start running without external libraries, but loads what it wants later. The three ways are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think dynamic linkage helps you much with platform independence.
Your second option seems like a reasonable way to be platform independence. Most of the code just calls your platform independent wrappers, while a small part of it is "dirty" with ifdefs.
I don't see how dynamic loading helps here.

Some pros and cons for dynamic loading:
1. Cons:
  a. Not the "straightforward" way, requires more work.
  b. Prevents standard tools (e.g. ldd) from analyzing dependenies (thus helping you undersatnd what you need to successfully run).
2. Pros:
  a. Allows loading only what you need (e.g. depending on command line arguments), or unloading what you don't. This can save memory.
  b. Lets you generate library names in more complicated ways (e.g. read a list of plugins from a configuration file).